# Moved website location: Loading failed for the <script>

Tags: wordpress

Building a Wordpress site locally, I've moved the website's location from localhost/company to the root (so localhost). I've gone into the settings in phpMyAdmin and changed the siteurl and home to 'http://localhost'.

Initially the site loads almost correctly (missing some images, elements etc). I presume these missing things are down to me not going changing the links using MySQL or the Velvet Blues Plugin.

However, when I refresh the entire website structure fails. Only a few elements actually load. If I inspect, I see the same error over and over.

> Loading failed for the  with source "http://localhost/company/wp-content/themes/grandtour/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js".

This error continues referencing just about any JS file within /wp-content/ or /wp-includes/.

I'm unsure why it's still looking into /company/ despite me changing the phpMyAdmin settings.

Edit: A large amount of the JS files are being linked to like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

So it would appear that 'template_url' is still seen as localhost/company. Should this have changed when I changed 'siteurl' and 'home'?

Edit 2: The problem is now also occurring when I upload the site to a live domain, so it's not a localhost issue.

Comment: Have you tried <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?> instead of blog_info("template_url");?  Also then just to make sure, i'd resave the permalinks

Comment: @neilk Thanks, I'll look at doing this. Odd though, I'm getting the same errors when I upload to a live domain. Surely there's got to be a better way than going through all files finding any time a JS file is linked to.

Comment: No problem, one more thing I'd do just in case it's an issue is delete the .htaccess file (keep a backup), resave permalinks and give it a try.

Comment: Hmmm, might be on to something there. In the .htaccess file I can see `RewriteBase /company/` and `RewriteRule . /company/index.php` - but deleting the file didn't have any affect.

Comment: delete the htaccess and then save permalinks again it will generate htaccess again.

Comment: make sure you changes the `siteurl` and `homeurl` in `wp_options` table in phpmyadmin

Comment: @noman - as I say in my question, I've already done this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, to solve the issue, I used this search and replace tool for WP databases. https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

I'd updated the links using MySQL and also attempted using the Velvet Blues plugin, which is what I usually use without issue. However, this tool was able to find an additional 8 entries, which when updates, solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 thing you need to do when changing your website domain name or URL.

The first thing you would want to double check is that your SQL entries reflect the correct new URL. The SQL statement below will adjust the URL's inside `wp_options`, `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://oldsite-url.com', 'http://newsite-url.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://oldsite-url.com', 'http://newsite-url.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://oldsite-url.com', 'http://newsite-url.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, 'http://oldsite-url.com','http://newsite-url.com');
```

The next thing you want to adjust is your `.htaccess` file. The quickest way to do this is to go to *Settings* -> *Permalinks* and click save.

This will regenerate your `.htaccess` file, assuming that your new server has got the mod_rewrite rules enabled (most do). As mentioned in your comments, deleting the `.htaccess` is also a potential fix (but keep a backup just in case).

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. I've followed your instructions, which did remove any mention of the old URL from my .htaccess file, however, the issue still persists.

Comment: @SamJohnson That's interesting... Could you possibly post the contents of your .htaccess file as it is now? I'm assuming it's still the same error where it's changing your template URL's to reflect your localhost/old URL?

Comment: I've managed to sort the issue. Thanks for your efforts in helping - I'll post how I solved it in an answer now.

Comment: Wonderful - I'm quite keen to see what the error was :) Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

it is always better to keep your site with-in the directory instead moving to `localhost` which is primary location of your websites.
Primary location means where you can setup multiple websites in a directory.

If you are curious about URL structure you should look for `Virtual Host`.

Here is the setup guide on [cloudways.com](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/configure-virtual-host-on-windows-10-for-wordpress/)

So, Keep your site in htdocs folder if you are using XAMPP. and setup VHOST for pretty URL's.

after setup the V-HOST URL would be like `http://yoursite.html`

Everything will work perfectly without any error.

Comment: Thanks for your input but I don't think that actually solves my problem. I've just attempted to upload the site to my actual domain and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: in that case you didn't mentioned about uploading the site to main domain. please edit your question instead localhost environment problem.\

Comment: At the time I hadn't attempted to upload it to a live domain. I've updated the question.